# Постфиксный инкремент/декремент. Не понимаю логику вычисления

Tags: java, инкремент

Я столкнулся с недопониманием логики вычисления в java. Есть такое выражение:

```java
int i = 0;
int u = 2;

i += 3 + u--;
```

Результат = 5.
Вопрос: Почему 5, если i = 0 + 3 + (2-1) == 4.

Другой вопрос по вычислению, есть цикл:

```java
int i = 0;
int u = 2;

for (i = 2; i++ < 12; i += 3 + u--) {
    u += i;
}

System.out.println(u);
```

Результат = 15. Почему 15?

Буду очень благодарен, кто объяснит.

Comment: Постфиксный декремент. Выражение `u--` уменьшает `u` на единицу, но возвращает значение, хранившееся в переменной `u` **до** уменьшения. Т.е. `u = 1; i = u--;`, в переменной `u` — ноль, в переменной `i` — единица.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var i = 0;
var u = 2;

for (i = 2; 
    (console.log(`i before loop check = ${i}`) || i++ < 12) && !console.log(`i after  loop check = ${i}`); 
    i += 3 + u--) {
  u += i;
  console.log(`i = ${i}, u = ${u}`);
}

console.log("Final u =", u);
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что при постфиксном инкременте/дикременте переменной `u` новое значения присваивается в последнюю очередь, то есть после того, как мы прибавили `u` к выражению.

Как работает унарный плюс, с унарным минусом логика така же:

```
int a = i++; <=> int a = i; i = i + 1;
```

Есть ещё и префиксный инкремент: `++u`:

```
int a = ++i; <=> i = i + 1; int a = i;
```